# Change animation direction with variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I searched this topics and i find some responses but they didnt seem to work for my code. Part of my code is this:

```
var direction = "left";
var speedvar = 3000;
var container_w = parseInt($("#lr-s").width());

$("#lr-s ul#"+number).animate({"left": "-="+container_w}, speedvar, "linear", function() {});
```

If i set the direction manually it works ok, but when i do this:

```
$("#lr-s ul#"+number).animate({direction: "-="+container_w}, speedvar, "linear", function() {});
```

Putting the "direction" variable dosnt seem to work. I need that the direction changes ("left, "right", "bottom", "top") so changing the symbol -= for += dosnt fit for me. I also tried:

```
var settings = {};
settings[direction] = container_w;
$("#lr-s ul#"+number).animate(settings, speedvar, "linear", function() {});
```

and

```
var settings = {"left": "-="+container_w};
$("#lr-s ul#"+number).animate(settings, speedvar, "linear", function() {});
```

Nothing worked with variables for the direction. Changin the direction manually works ok but i want to set a variable to simplify changing the direction for the user of the plugin. Help please. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how to explain it really well but I don't think the property attribute can be a var, the value can be a var but the attribute itself should not be a var. I don't know if this is true but it makes sense in my head. It's like if you are defining a var in js, var name; Right now you are trying to change the "var" part in that declaration when the only thing you can change is the "name". Sorry if that sounds confusing or untrue.

Comment: Part of the problem in animating 'left' and 'right' separately is that you're setting two different values.  So essentially if you go 'left' first and then go 'right' your element is going to have something like:  <div style="left:20px;right:10px;"></div> which ends up being really gross

Comment: I understand what you are saying Huangism but i hope there is a way because if not i will have to put conditionals and repeat the whole animation code with diferent parameters every time and i dont think thats a good practice. Jeschafe you misunderstood me, i know that i can not set 2 parameters; I only want one at the time. My idea is that you complete the direction variable in the code and then the program will animate only that way.

Answer (score 1):

here are some notes to make it work:

1) the correct way to build an object with dynamically assigned property names:

```
var settings = {};
settings[direction] = scrollAmount;
$("#lr-s ul#"+number).animate(settings, speedvar, "linear", function() {});
```

2) don't forget to reset currently animated property after you start to animate 'opposite' property. In case when two opposite properties got assigned to an element, a browser uses 'prioritized' properties to position this element. It means 'left' property wins over 'right', and 'top' wins over 'bottom'.

```
$('#bullet').css('left', '');
```

Here is an example:
html:

```
<div style="position:relative; margin-top:100px; height:100px; background-color:Yellow;">
    <p id="ship" style="position:absolute;">ship</p>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="Anim.changeDir();">change direction</button>
```

script:

```
    $(function () {
        Anim.start('left', '+=500');
    });

    var Anim = {

        lastDir: 'left',
        lastShift: '+=500',

        $el: function () {
            return $('#ship');
        },

        start: function (dir, shift) {

            dir = dir || (this.lastDir == 'left' ? 'right' : 'left');
            shift = shift || this.lastShift;

            var prop = {};
            prop[dir] = shift;
            this.$el().animate(prop, 5000);

            if (this.lastDir) {
                this.$el().css(this.lastDir, '');
            }

            this.lastDir = dir;
            this.lastShift = shift;
        },

        stop: function () {
            this.$el().stop();
            return this;
        },

        changeDir: function () { 
            this.stop();
            this.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (direction){
        case 'right':
            jQuery(element).animate({ 'right': offset }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```